# How to write input data processor from known html id?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape this web page: http://goo.gl/Eqfiuy

I want to give the input as date from a list and scrapy should give that value to the form and gets redirected to to the results page by giving response 'print report'. Then I want to parse the data in it.

My question is how to make scrapy to give input date to the html id?

I am using scrapy 0.16.5, ubuntu 12.04, firefox+firebug+firefinder

Please give an example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this form makes a POST request to `http://164.100.167.12/pwd/report.php`. Here's how you can simulate it in Scrapy:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["http://164.100.167.12/"]
    report_date = '30/07/2013'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield FormRequest(url='http://164.100.167.12/pwd/report.php',
                          method='POST',
                          callback=self.parse_page,
                          formdata={'reportdate': self.report_date})

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # save the pdf
        with open('output.pdf', 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Note, that there is an `embed` tag in the resulting html, there is a pdf inside - it's saved into `output.pdf`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all thanks for your kind help. I encountered error saying no spider found in file. I am using the command $ scrapy runspider file.py. This is the error : _runspider: error: No spider found in file: file.py_ . Sorry but I am new to using Scrapy. Please tell me the commands which I should use in the terminal to repeat your process.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't call it `file.py`. Choose another name.

Comment: Thanks it is running :)

Comment: If i have to run the spider for say from some starting date to end date, what should I do?. Instead of having report date as single variable.

Comment: I use this code to generate list of dates
'start_date = date(2012, 06, 15)
    end_date = date(2012, 06, 20)
    for i in rrule(DAILY, dtstart= start_date, until=end_date):
        report_date = i.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')'
But how to make the spider to scrape for 10 days and create 10 pdf.

Comment: Just make a loop in `start_requests` and yield `Request` inside.

Comment: def start_requests(self):
        start = date(2012, 06, 15)
        end = date(2012, 06, 20)
        for i in rrule(DAILY, dtstart= start, until=end):
            report_date = i.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            yield FormRequest(url='http://164.100.167.12/pwd/report.php',
                              method='POST',
                              callback=self.parse_page,
                              formdata={'reportdate': self.report_date})
    def parse_page(self, response):
        #save the pdf
        with open('%s.pdf' %report_date, 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

Comment: I used the above code but getting error, saying myspider has no attribute report_date

Comment: I am attaching the gist you can edit in it if you want to https://gist.github.com/Kirubaharan/6138100

Comment: I've added a comment to the gist, please check.

Comment: Sorry but still some problem in naming the file name representing the dates properly. I have commented back in gist. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I've added a comment, please check.

Comment: I have added 'meta' but when I run the spider it is saying syntax error in Formrequest section.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to alecxe, this is the working code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from datetime import date
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

 class MySpider(BaseSpider):
     name = "tnpwd"
     allowed_domains = ["http://164.100.167.12/"]
     start_urls = ["http://164.100.167.12/pwd/report.php"]

     def start_requests(self):
         start_date = date(2012, 06, 15)
         end_date = date(2012, 06, 20)
         for i in rrule(DAILY, dtstart= start_date, until=end_date):
             report_date = i.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
             file_name = i.strftime('%d_%m_%Y')
             yield FormRequest(url='http://164.100.167.12/pwd/report.php',
                               method='POST',
                               callback=self.parse_page,
                               formdata={'reportdate': report_date},
                               meta = {'file_name': file_name})
     def parse_page(self, response):
        a= response.meta['file_name']
        print 'downloading %s' %a
        with open('/home/USERNAME/Documents/test/%s.pdf' %a, 'w') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```